# Why is "several two hours' meetings" wrong?

Tags: possessives, exam-questions

Why is "several two hours' meetings" wrong? Any insight will be greatly appreciated.
 
It is from an ECPE practice exam grammar section question.

> The boss won't be able to see you today as he has got several______meetings.
>   
>   a) two hours 
>   b) two-hour 
>   c) two hours'    
>   d) two hour's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We’ll get the simpler cases out of the way first: *two hours meetings* and *two hour’s meetings* are both wrong. The first combines has two nouns in a row (*hours* and *meetings*) without any kind of word to relate them. Some nouns can be used be used as an adjective, but *hours* isn’t one of them (*hour* could be, as we’ll get to, but not *hours*). And *two hour’s meetings* is wrong because if there are two of them, then the hours are plural, and the plural possessive is *hours’*, not *hour’s*.

The hyphenated term *two-hour* combines the two words into a single adjective: whatever noun *two-hour* modifies, we know that noun had a duration of two hours. So grammatically, this is valid. Furthermore, this is the correct answer to the question simply because **this is how English speakers would say it.**

It is fairly common to put a hyphen between two adjectives to indicate that the first adjective is modifying the second, rather than both of them separately modifying the noun. Contrast with *two hour meetings* which would imply two meetings, each an hour long, rather than a single meeting that was two hours long. (Though, to my ear, *hour meeting* sounds strange and I would very likely expand it to *two hour-long meetings*—but I would not say *two-hour-long meetings*. I am not personally sure why that is. The difference may very well to disambiguate between the two possibilities. Also note that the preceding *several* rules out *two hour-long meetings*—either there are several or there are exactly two; using both adjectives is confusing and wrong.)

Now then, on to your actual question.

The phrase *two hours’ meetings* is grammatical, and **could** be used. You hear things like *in two hours’ time* occasionally, meaning “two hours from now”—but it sounds somewhat archaic, makes me think of a Victorian-era British gentleman. English speakers will understand *two hours’ time*. But I cannot think of any other noun that *hours’* could be applied to—really, what does an hour possess other than time? I guess you could use *two hours’ minutes* to mean 120 minutes or *two hours’ seconds* to mean 7200 seconds, but I have never heard that usage and would be confused by it, probably requiring confirmation or clarification. But *two hours’ meetings*? A meeting is not something a pair of hours could possess. That makes the possessive here nonsensical. Which doesn’t always stop English, of course, but in this case it does. Ultimately, as with everyone else, *two hours’ meetings* is wrong simply because English speakers do not say that.

Comment: Many thanks. We do however say "a two hours' walk" whereas "two hours' walks" does not sound right. Could the problem be that the structure with the genitive only works if the nouns are singular?

Comment: @Terry That’s a great point, and it might be, though *two hours’ meeting* still doesn’t sound like something I would expect any English speaker to ever say.

Comment: @Terry Although I think *a two hours' walk* is somewhat better (relatively speaking) than *two hours' walks*, I also find it awkward and would never use it myself. But I think the difference between the two, idiomatically speaking, is that the plural version involves a repetitive *s* sound that is unnatural to perform with your tongue.