# "I booked a three-day" in place of "I booked a three-days"

Tags: meaning, difference

What is the reason to say " I booked a three-day accommodation in the “Wild life Nature Reserve” camping." in place of " I booked a three-days accommodation in the “Wild life Nature Reserve” camping.

If three are more than one, in ohter words, it is plural, why to use the word "day" in singular? "three-day" in place of "three-days".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "several two hours' meetings" wrong?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/183230/why-is-several-two-hours-meetings-wrong) Also [a two hour leave VS. two hours leave](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/45977/a-two-hour-leave-vs-two-hours-leave) and [why the use of a singular noun instead of plural?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/59143/why-the-use-of-a-singular-noun-instead-of-plural) And probably several more - this is a common question here on ELL.

Comment: 'Three days' accommodation needs the old apostrophe! Never sure why, but someone said.

Answer (score 1):

We say "a three-day vacation" (or "holiday", in British English) just like we say "a five-star hotel", "a two-car family" or "a two-horse race". There is no need to pluralise the number of days (or stars, cars, or horses).

This is because, when we refer to "*a* vacation" we are using "three-day" as an adjective, attributing the days spent as a *quality* of the vacation. Adjectives in English do not take the plural ending.

If, however, you don't use the article "a" in front of 'vacation', then "three days" may be used in the *possessive*, for example:

> "I've just booked three days' vacation".

This is because the three days is a *measure*, not an attribute. It is like saying "six dollars' worth of gas".

---

I should just add that I don't think the former works with the word you used in your examples - "accommodation". I don't think days can be an attribute of accommodation, and it does not sound natural. I think you should use "three days' accomodation".

Answer (score 0):

Three-day is a hyphenated **compound word**. It has a different meaning to the individual words.

In this case, *three-day* is an adjective that describes a type of camping plan. It's inferred there are other types, probably *2-day accommodations*, *1-week accommodations*, etc.

Breaking the **compound word** into individual words changes the meaning. '*I booked three days of camping…*' or '*I booked accommodations for three days…*' tells us how long the vacation will be, but does not infer a type or package deal.